# Laravel Glide installation - where do I put the config information?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am interested in installing Glide in Laravel for an image server I need to build.

There are 3 main steps in the installation:

1. Run a Composer command

   `composer require league/glide-laravel`
2. This step is called 'Configuration', it shows the following PHP code

Configuration:

```
use League\Glide\ServerFactory;
use League\Glide\Responses\LaravelResponseFactory;    
$server = ServerFactory::create([
    'response' => new LaravelResponseFactory(app('request'))
]);
```

... and step 3, which is a working example.

My question is, where does the step 2. 
configuration code go?

I can't see anywhere obvious in the 'config' folder. Disclaimer: I'm a newbie to Laravel with only two sites built so far.

thank you.

Comment: almost 6 years later and the docs are still ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration code belongs in the default image controller. It is confusing in the documentation but I placed the code in the controller and it works.